# How to add a caption to an image in Pages

Tags: pages

How does one create a caption for an image in Pages? In Word it is easy, you simply right click on the image and “Insert Caption…”, but I cannot find any way to do it at all in Pages?

You can set a ‘Description’ on an image, however that only affects voiceover, which I do appreciate! But I also want the ability to move the image and it’s caption together.

I am using Pages 5.5.2, I understand that this is easier in Pages ’09, but I don't have that version anymore…

***Edit:*** The only method that I have found that vaguely works is to create a new text box, manually make the text box the same size as the image, and text, set the paragraph style to caption, and, *finally*, group the image and the text box together so that they are treated as a unit. I hope that there is a simpler way that I have just missed somehow!

Comment: Typically you would just type in the caption below the image and style it as "Caption"

Comment: @sdmeyers the problem with that is that then I have to maintain the location of the caption and the location of the image separately, even to the extent of making sure that they remain on the same page. Even worse, if I have two images in a line, then centring the captions under each image is nigh on impossible.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: Insert > Text Box. In the Wrap Inspector, set to Floating. Enter text. Adjust position. Select both photo and Text Box, then Arrange > Group.

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks. That is what I updated in the edit, I was hoping for an easier method that my child could do easily, but this process isn't really that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no automatic way of adding a caption.

- If your image is inline, add the text below using the Caption text style.
- If your image is floating, you'll need to add a text box below the image. You can group these if you wish.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but I am afraid it will be the best I get! 

Comment: After making the first one, set the image as a placeholder, then just command+D to duplicate for more. Formatting will be applied.

Answer (score 13):

I often make a table that has two rows. Paste your image into the top cell, put your caption in the cell below, and remove the borders. The figure scales with the size of the cell and the caption moves with the text. However, I can't do this on pages in iCloud, so if you are going back and forth with iCloud editing, grouping of objects seems more robust.

Comment: The main problem with this, is if you have a table of references for images, using a table row, it doesn't appear on it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to add Table Label in the Inspector for others who might be looking at how to add a caption. Click on Table in Inspector, and in the section with Header Footer select Table Label.